# Will using the "bread trick" to solder copper lines cause potential issues with bread in the water heater?

Tags: plumbing, soldering, copper-pipe

I see in many places advice to use a ball of bread to seal off the inside of a copper pipe before soldering connections to it. The reasoning is always that when the water is turned back on the bread will be pulverized and expelled through a faucet. Recently I was fixing a line going to my hot water heater. In my case, I was able to dry the pipe sufficient for soldering the new fitting but I've been thinking: If I had used a ball of bread to stop up the line, it would have been pushed into the water heater tank where I expect it would be stuck fermenting and rotting in my potable water system. Could this be a problem in practice or am I over thinking it?

Comment: Somehow I started thinking of the movie "The Blob".   Do not know if the bread would float and be washed out though the hot line, or sink to the bottom.

Comment: It's rather a matter of speculation and risk tolerance. I'm not sure we can answer with confidence. For my part I avoid the bread thing anyway, mostly because we rarely have highly processed white bread on hand (blech), but also because it just doesn't seem like a modern strategy. I'd rather use vacuum, compressed air, or a new joint somewhere suitable to clear the pipe.

Comment: I used the "bread trick" 30+ years ago. I could never get it to seal well enough to keep the joint dry. Maybe it's because I wasn't using white "bread", but only something that tasted better and, therefore, wasn't suitable for other purposes.

Comment: Is this just to address the issue of residual water in the pipes even after shutoff?

Comment: If you do plan on trying the bread trick (I wouldn’t, but others might have a different risk/reward equation in mind), only use bland white bread — I’ve heard of seeds and whole wheat flakes destroying dishwashers.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the hot water is drawn from the top of the water heater. Floating bread should be quickly purged. But there exists water insoluble flux, so use that stuff if there's a tiny drip-drip-drip somewhere behind your connection that can't be diverted through a valve somewhere else.

For sufficient temperature, you can't get away with just heating the joint alone. You have to heat up a length of pipe going upstream from the joint. Tipping the torch at about a 45 degree angle along the pipe maximizes the heat input. I suppose you could go nuts with an oxy-propane or -acetylene torch, but if the drip is that substantial, then you should fix it.

Comment: I'd have thought all common flux was water-insoluble. Anyway, the issue tends to be the inability to heat a joint to sweating temp due to heat sink into the water. I'm not sure how your proposal addresses that.

Comment: @isherwood, see https://oateyassetscdn.azureedge.net/assets/Document/raw_03_ClimateSmoothSolderingPaste_SUBMITTAL_001.pdf. "Very slightly soluble."

Comment: I heated the upstream side about 30cm away from the joint with a heat gun, while using my blowtorch on the actual join. That meant the drops of water trickling along were vapourised before they got near the joint. The heat gun in question was powerful enough to solder pipes with good access - which I didn't have. (@isherwood, basically just doubling the power input, but biased towards the wet side overcomes the heat sinking)